# Unexpected whitespace using sqsh in command substitution

Tags: shell-script, quoting, whitespace

Below shell script instruction behave in weird way

```
ARG_DATE=`sqsh -S $SERVER -U $DB_USER -P $DB_PASSWORD -D dbname -h<<END
SET NOCOUNT ON
go
select convert(varchar, PRIOR_COB_DATE, 112) from TABLE
go
END`
echo $ARG_DATE

if [ "${ARG_DATE}" != "1" ] && [ "${ARG_DATE}" != " " ]; then
    if [ ${ARG_DATE/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/1} = "1" ]; then
        PRIOR_POSITION_DATE=${ARG_DATE}
        echo "assigned " $PRIOR_POSITION_DATE
    else
        echo "Date must be in follow format: YYYYMMDD"
        echo "POSITION_DATE will be used."
    fi
fi



URL_PARAMS="HttpAutosysJobExecutor/NotificationEmailGenerator.job?prior_cob_date=${PRIOR_POSITION_DATE}"
    echo $URL_PARAMS
    echo ${CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE} "http://${SERVER_ADDRESS}:${SERVER_PORT}/HTTP/${URL_PARAMS}"
        wget -o ${CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE} "http://${SERVER_ADDRESS}:${SERVER_PORT}/HTTP/${URL_PARAMS}"
        if [ -f ${CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE} ]; then
            RESPONSE_STATUS=`grep -o '200 OK' ${CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE}`
            if [ -z "${RESPONSE_STATUS}" ]; then
                echo Login failed.
                exit 3
            fi
        #    rm ${CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE}
        fi
```

while executing wget I am getting so many whitespaces becasue of whitespaces database procedure is failing to cast string in DB Date, using `sed` I can remove whitespaces but I want to know the possible reason of this.

**Log in CONNECTION_STATUS_FILE**

```
http://XXXXX:7001/MYAPP/HttpAutosysJobExecutor/NotificationEmailGenerator.job?prior_cob_date=%2020130523%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

Comment: So you have a problem with `${PRIOR_POSITION_DATE}` but don't tell us how `${PRIOR_POSITION_DATE}` is created / set and now we shall guess?

Comment: @echo ${PRIOR_POSITION_DATE} shows,  " 20130523" but there are not traling spaces. trailing spaces are issue.

Comment: Are **you** really telling **me** that it's of no use to show us how `${PRIOR_POSITION_DATE}` gets assigned its value?

Comment: updated question with how i am setting value.

Comment: And what is the output you get when running the script, `assigned ...` or `POSITION_DATE will be used`?

Comment: **assigned ...** , it also contains whitespace i have figured out using your solution but do not know why I m getting it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8987/discussion-between-alpesh-gediya-and-hauke-laging)

Comment: That may suggest that this need to be tagged with sqsh and not wget then. If the whitespace appears earlier -the wget stuff later is noise.

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @DannyStaple I retagged the question.

Comment: Ah - I cannot see your edit yet Hauke. Your tags make more sense than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` Does not show you the whitespace at the end. For that you need something like `echo "${URL_PARAMS}x"`. You can do `set -x` immediately before the `wget` call and `set +x` immediately after to see how `wget` is called.

The problem is the shell's word splitting:

```
${ARG_DATE/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/1} = "1"
```

instead of

```
"${ARG_DATE/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/1}" = "1"
```

A solution would be to put this before that (fixed) line:

```
ARG_DATE="${ARG_DATE// /}"
```

Comment: but just after fetching data from DB `"${ARG_DATE}test"` evaluted as `20130523          test`

Comment: @AlpeshGediya So what? Do you ask where the other spaces come from? Are you sure you tested that with the quotes (`echo "${ARG_DATE}test"`)?

Comment: I have never used this **ARG_DATE="${ARG_DATE// /}"** synatax can you please provide explanation about this in your answer..

Comment: @AlpeshGediya You use nearly that in your script... The difference is that `/` replaces the first occurrence and `//` all occurrences of the string. I.e. all spaces get replaced by – nothing (i.e. deleted).

Comment: @AlpeshGediya What does "failing to split" mean?